# Determining Source Quality with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, traffic

What I am trying to do is set up a report (either on the new or the old analytics setup) that tells me the average "Pages per Visit" of all traffic "Sources". I can get that through Traffic Sources->All Traffic Sources, and then sorting by pages per visit, but that puts a lot of junk (one or two visits) sources on top, if I sort it by number of visits, I get a fair amount of junk (stumbleupon.com with only around 2 pages per visit).

What I would like is that same chart, sorted by pages per visit, with visits above a threshold of 10. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From the original GA *All Traffic Sources* report, click the *Advanced Filter* link at the bottom of the report table
2. Change the *Filter* from *Source/Medium* to *Visits*, select *Greater than or equal to* from the adjacent drop-down, and enter *10* in the field
3. Click the *Apply Filter* button
4. Click the *Pages/Visit* column to sort